# EF: Map class to a column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

i have a class that could be represented by an integer.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyClass FromCode(int code)
    {
        // implementation here
    }
}
```

`MyClass` could be represented by `Code` property.

Is there any way that i could map `MyClass` by `Code` property to a column and read it back to `MyClass` using `FromCode` method ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use `MyContext.MyClass.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == code);` and have EF populate it for you?

Comment: `MyClass` is an enumeration class so it will have limited set of instances. I want to skip database to simplify migration when `MyClass` is growing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible (currently ;)).

But I think you can work around it. I'm just guessing what are you doing, so bear with me. I suppose you're getting the `Name` from some kind of dictionary based on `Code`. If so you could still let Entity Framework populate `Code` and have the look-up logic inside `getter` of  `Name` (optionally you can cache the value)

Comment: I see, so it's not possible. I guess i could work on the work around you mention. Thanks @cincura.net